# STM VCP USB_BUSY?

Tags: serial, stm32, firmware, stm32f0

I am using STM32 VCP firmware, and I am sending data to my PC application

If i did not open my serial port in PC, and my firmware keep on sending the data it will cause USB_BUSY to happen, (i think the firmware transmission buffer is full and it is waiting for the PC side to receive data)

when I open the serial port in my PC application during the USB_BUSY it will cause the PC to hang!

May i know how can I handle the USB_BUSY state in my firmware? how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please tell us how your system is connected? STM32's VCP need a USB and USART connection, how do you connect them?

Comment: i dont use USART, i remove the USART component and directly send the data to the USB endpoint

Comment: Umm, you mean your device isn't a USART->USB translator. What's your front end in PC? RS232 Hyperteminal?

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: @diverger i posted my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My PC side is USB, emulate as VCP

I have managed to solve the problem but not a good solution thou...

I added 2 things:

1. a communication protocol
2. clearing the tx buffer to empty

I added a new protocol which is START and STOP command, I need my PC side to send a STAT command to my firmware, before it starts to send data to my PC

Whenever it is USB_BUSY mode, I will send a empty buffer to let the VCP firmware to trigger an interrupt, and this will clear my USB_BUSY

I just added this line of code only

```
USBD_LL_DataInStage((USB handler), (endpoint), 0); // 0 = empty buffer
```

I would love to know if anyone has better solution!

**UPDATE!!!**

I have finally solved this problem, be replacing the entire STM32 HAL driver for USB CDC back to the Standard Peripheral library for USB CDC!

and there is no more problem with it! I run into many issues using HAL driver from STM32, it is very buggy! if you encounter problem with it, try to switch back to Standard Peripheral library!

Comment: Yes, adding flow control is better. You can also try change "APP_RX_DATA_SIZE" in usbd_conf.h. And several other macros.

Comment: @diverger yup! tried that but not much changes, i guess once the USB BUSY is triggered, the host could not send some command to ask for the descriptor from the firmware(that why it hangs when opening the port), from my understanding when opening the serial port, there is some USB protocol that the host needs to communicate with the device to ask for some descriptor(port information) and endpoint info and etc

Comment: If you don't open the serial port in PC, your driver on PC side won't receive the data, so your device will soon busy. But when you open the your serial, your driver on PC may try to send some configuration command to your device, but your device is busy sending now, so the PC hang......

Comment: @diverger yup, you are right! and one more thing i not sure, is that USB is not bidirection? for each 1ms frame that windows schedule, it could only be either send or receive right? it cant be both? am I right>?

Comment: USB is a bidirection protocol indeed. But it's a protocol based on master-slave mechanism. All communication activity is issued by master, the slave can only response. So, this where the problem is.

Comment: @diverger I see! so I cant send and write at the same time right? if I do that, the USB host will schedule either my send or read first then the 2nd action?

Comment: Umm, you can image that, USB line are D+ D-, the data are represented by the level difference between them, so it's basically a half-duplex, any time it can only have data in one direction.

Comment: You can try first open the com on your PC, then sending data to PC. If your code is based on the example from ST, i think you should read them carefully, then you can make it more suit your application. Because ST's example is a USART->USB->USART structure.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a handshaking problem.

The VCP driver fake your USB to a RS232 port, when you open such a port, it may need configure the baudrate, data format, parity, stop bit, etc.. So, your device shouldn't send data to your host when the configuration not done.

So, if you must use VCP class, your device should send data after the com configuration done. Or you can make your own protocol, even your own USB class, but this need rewrite the USB driver on PC side.

This is the [USB CDC class definitions](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/CDC1.2_WMC1.1_012011.zip) (which VPC based on), may give you some help.